# How do I access the data in this dynamic import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

How do you handle objects that are dynamically imported?

I have this in package.json:

```
process.env.VUE_APP_CONFIG='./specialconfig/config.js'
```

In my Vue component, I have:

```
const myobj = import(process.env.VUE_APP_CONFIG)
```

config.js simply has in it:

```
export const cat = {
  name: “Bob”,
}
```

If I console.log this in a vue component, it is returning a promise and resolves and I can see the data. What is the best approach to resolving and using it the properties in config.js?

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve it using the `then` method of the Promise.

```
import(process.env.VUE_APP_CONFIG).then(myobj => {
  console.log(myobj);
});
```

Or use the `async` / `await` syntax to store the value from the Promise in a variable and use it in the same function scope.

```
(async () => {
  const myobj = await import(process.env.VUE_APP_CONFIG);
  console.log(myojb);
});
```

Both options are equally effective. The rest all comes down to preference.